# Firebase.util - similar intersections with completely different results

Tags: angularjs, firebase, intersection

I'm working on an angular project that uses Firebase as it's sole backend, angularFire for some synchronisation cases and I'm using this tool **Firebase.util** for dealing with shared resources. My case is this:

```js
{
    users {
        user1 : {
            tasks : {
                active : {
                    task1 : true,
                    task2 : true
                },
                archived : {
                    task3 : true,
                    task4 : true
                }
            },
            ...
        },
        tasks : {
            task1 : {
                users : {
                    user1 : true,
                    user2 : true
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    },

}
```

and I'm dealing with the query like this:

```js
var tasksRef     = new $window.Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/tasks');

function _userActiveTasksRef(userId) {
    return new $window.Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + userId + '/tasks/active');
}
function _userArchivedTasksRef(userId) {
    return new $window.Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + userId + '/tasks/archived');
}

function getActive(userId) {
    var interRef = $window.Firebase.util.intersection(_userActiveTasksRef(userId), tasksRef);
    return $firebase(interRef).$asArray();
}
function getArchived(userId) {
    var interRef = $window.Firebase.util.intersection(_userArchivedTasksRef(userId), tasksRef);
    return $firebase(interRef).$asArray();
}
```

On the first case, when I intersect the active tasks with the "all tasks" ref everything works fine but when I try to perform the same operation with the archived tasks the intersection is always empty. I've already logged the individual queries and everything is working as expected, only the intersection doesn't seem to work. Is there any caveat that I'm missing? The two queries are being loaded at the same time if that matters.. the result is being stored in a controller like this:

```js
this.tasks = {
    active:   tasks.getActive(currentUser.uid),
    archived: tasks.getArchived(currentUser.uid)
};
```

Comment: You should be using Angularfire to build your Angular/Firebase application, it's designed for that.

Comment: I am. Firebase.util is a library that plays well with angularfire, it returns an intersected instance that works just like a native firebase one, so it can be used with angular fire as I'm using like on `return $firebase(interRef).$asArray();`

Comment: Updated my post so I can make that point clearer. Thanks @itcouldevenbeaboat.

Comment: If you get the values from `interRef.on('value'` are they correct? If so, can you remove AngularFire from the equation and simply the question to only use Firebase's Web/JavaScript API and firebase-util?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried it now and both the *_userArchivedTasksRef* and the *interRef* variables returns normally with the `ref.on('value')` method. The problem is the inner join made by the Firebase.join lib is returning `null`. Although the exact same case occurs with the *_userActiveTasksRef* but with a positive result. (the data structures are exactly the same)

Comment: I just wanted to get confirmation that the problem occurs in the `$asArray()` conversion inside `getArchived`. Since that seems to be the case, you might want to reconsider your statement that "firebase.util is a library that plays well with angularfire". I'll wait for its author to show up and confirm that (that's your cue Kato).

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. I meant to say that both the **_userArchivedTasksRef** and **TasksRef** returned normally with the `ref.on('value', fn)`. **interRef** comes back `null` even if not passing it through the `$firebase().$asArray()`

Comment: @GeorgesBoris something doesn't jive here. If it's always returning null, then most likely your archived tasks are in a different data path (not shown in your example), which would make sense; that's what archiving is. So you'd need a different `tasksRef` for the archived data. What you've shown here would work fine and obviously is a poor representation--probably too simplified--of the real model that is failing.